# Ruby: Regular expression to match which strings made up either space , tab or new line and nothing else

Tags: ruby, regex, string, pattern-matching

I trying to formulate a regular expression which will match only those strings which are made up of only 3 types of characters: tab, space and new line. For ex.

```
String1 = "        \t      "
String2 = "\n\n"
String3 = "  \t      \n \n       \n    "
```

All above strings should match the regular expression.
I tried this : `%r/[ \n]+/`

But this is also matching strings having space and new line but apart from those many other characters also, like

```
string4 = "  I am a boy \n"
```

My expression is also match string4 which it should not match.

I am not able to fix it. It will be great if someone could come up with a solution to fix this.

Comment: Question is not clear. "Space, tab, and newline" or "Space and newline"--which?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the regex that the WHOLE string must fit, rather than part of a string. Do this with the ^ and $ operators, which mean 'start of file' and 'end of file' respectively:

```
/^[\t\n ]+$/
```

This site, and sites like it, can be useful:

http://regex101.com/

Comment: `\s` matches all whitespace, so could be a short-cut for `[\t\n ]` if you're OK with `\r` appearing in there too.